# XSLT: To collect xml files from all folders of name 9000 series using xslt Collection

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Please suggest for the 'Collection' function in XSLT to fetch info from 'main.xml' from sub directories names start with 9000 series, i.e.,
D:/Author-Index/9001/main.xml, D:/Author-Index/9002/main.xml, D:/Author-Index/9003/main.xml, D:/Author-Index/9009/main.xml, D:/Author-Index/90nn/main.xml  (nth number)

But not from D:/Author-Index/939/main.xml (because three digit folder).

I am getting error using `collection('file:///D:/AuthorIndex/9[0-9][0-9][0-9]?select=*main.xml;recurse=yes')`  to find folder name starts with `9[n][n][n]/main.xml`

XML1: D:/Author-Index/9001/main.xml

```
        <article>
  <fm>
    <title>Journey to Galaxy</title>
    <author><snm>Kishan</snm><fnm>TR</fnm></author>
  </fm>
  <body>
        <p>This article explian about Galaxy Journey</p>
  </body>
</article>
```

XML2: D:/Author-Index/9002/main.xml

```
    <article>
    <fm>
   <title>Journey to Mars</title>
   <author><snm>Rudramuni</snm><fnm>TP</fnm></author>
    </fm>
    <body>
    <p>This article explian about Mars Journey</p>
    </body>
</article>
```

XSLT: XSLT version 2

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:variable name="varCollection">
       <xsl:copy-of select="collection('file:///D:/AuthorIndex/9[0-9][0-9][0-9]?select=*main.xml;recurse=yes')"/>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="$varCollection//article">
        <xsl:element name="title1"><xsl:value-of select="//fm//title"/></xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="aug">
            <xsl:for-each select="//fm//author">
                <xsl:element name="au"><xsl:element name="snm"><xsl:value-of select="snm"/></xsl:element><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                      <xsl:element name="fnm"><xsl:value-of select="fnm"/></xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required Result:

```
    <article>
   <aug>
    <au><snm>Kishan</snm><fnm>TR</fnm></au>
    <title1>Journey to Galaxy</title1>
    <au><snm>Rudramuni</snm><fnm>TP</fnm></au>
    <title1>Journey to Mars</title1>
   </aug>
</article>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not very efficient, but you could use the [collection()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-collection) function to recursively scan ***all*** of the `D:/AuthorIndex` folders for `*main.xml` files and then use a predicate filter to select only those documents that are in the 9000 series folders:

```
<xsl:variable name="varCollection">
  <xsl:copy-of 
       select="collection('file:///D:/AuthorIndex/?select=*main.xml;recurse=yes')
         [matches(document-uri(.),'AuthorIndex/9[0-9][0-9][0-9]/.*?main.xml')]"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 1):

The form of URIs that are accepted by the [collection()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-collection) function varies from product to product. You are using a format that was first introduced in Saxon, and was subsequently adopted by some other products. However, the Saxon implementation certainly doesn't allow the collection URI to be a regular expression like this, and I would be surprised if other implementations do.

The answer is going to be product-specific. In Saxon, you could write your own [CollectionURIResolver](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!javadoc/net.sf.saxon.lib/CollectionURIResolver) to handle collection URIs in this form.

Comment: @Mads Hansen Sir, Thanks a lot for your suggestion. It is working perfectly as required.Sorry for late reply.